# how can I delete this regex with mysql

Tags: mysql, regexp-replace

I have a UDF regex_replace which replace CASEINSENSITIVE a regex. Now I would like to get the string inside `(`and `)` in this string. I did:

```
    SELECT regex_replace('[^0-9{MC.D}]+','',"HPLC Labor Öttl 1 Raumtemperatur(MC1.D.03.031)");
```

the output is, which is not desired: `C1mmMC1.D.03.031`

I would need. `MC1.D.03.031`  only.
How can I do this with a regex suitable to my UDF?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index:

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('HPLC Labor Öttl 1 Raumtemperatur(MC1.D.03.031)', '(', -1), ')', 1) ;
```

> ```
> mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('HPLC Labor Öttl 1 Raumtemperatur(MC1.D.03.031)', '(', -1), ')', 1) ;
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('HPLC Labor Öttl 1 Raumtemperatur(MC1.D.03.031)', '(', -1), ')', 1)  |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | MC1.D.03.031                                                                                         |
> +------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```